# Docker Compose: expose with scaling

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I scale container

```
  ports:
  - "8086-8090:8085"
```

But what if I needed it only inside my bridge network?
In other words, does it exists something like this?

```
  expose:
  - "8086-8090:8085"
```

UPDATED:
I have a master container:

- exposed to host network
- acts as a load balancer

I want to have N slaves of another container, exposed to assigned ports inside docker network (bot visible in host network)

Answer (score 1):

Connections between containers (over the Docker-internal bridge network) don't need `ports:` at all, and you can just remove that block.  You only need `ports:` to accept connections from outside of Docker.  If the process inside the container is listening on port 8085 then connections between containers will always use port 8085, regardless of what `ports:` mappings you have or if there is one at all.

`expose:` in a Compose file does almost nothing at all.  You never need to include it, and it's always safe to delete it.

(This wasn't the case in first-generation Docker networking. However, Compose files v2 and v3 always provide what the Docker documentation otherwise calls a "user-defined bridge network", that doesn't use "exposed ports" in any way.  I'm not totally clear why the archaic `expose:` and `links:` options were kept.)

Comment: So how do I scale only inside docker network?

To be clear - 
I have a master container: 
- exposed to host network
- acts as a load balancer
I want to have N slaves of another container, exposed to assigned ports inside docker network (bot visible in host network)

Comment: Internally, each container has its own IP address (not normally accessible from outside Docker) and Docker internally provides a DNS system.  So if the worker containers needed to connect back to the primary, they could call something like `primary:8085`, and the primary could call back to `worker_2:8085`; and this works without `ports:` or `expose:` settings for the workers.

Comment: Exactly! What I didn't know before, is that docker is having it's own DNS for name resolving. So if I have slave service on port 8080, and then run docker-compose with --scale parameter - this will then be resolved by Docker’s embedded DNS server, which will use a round robin implementation to resolve the DNS requests based on the service name and distribute them to the Docker containers!

Answer (score 0):

No extra changes needed!

Because of internal Docker DNS it 'hides' scaled instances under same port:

```
  version : "3.8"
  services:
    web:
      image: "nginx:latest"
      ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

then

```
docker-compose up -d --scale web=3
```

calling localhost:8080 will proxy requests to all instances using Round Robin!